# How to fix Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tRPAREN in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to build out a mutation in GraphQL for Rails and getting some issues with RuboCop and can't figure out how to fix the code:

```
resolve(Auth.protect lambda (_obj, inputs, ctx) do
  current_user = ctx[:current_user]
  if current_user.update(inputs.to_params)
    { user: current_user }
  else
    { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
  end
)
end
```

It's indicating on the parenthesis after ctx and before the last end. If I strip out the parenthesis OR I do lambda(_obj, inputs, ctx) I end up with:

```
Lint/Syntax: unexpected token kDO_block
```

Comment: What is the code trying to do? Are you trying to say `resolve(Auth.protect(some_lambda))` with the `do ... end` block as the lambda's body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resolve lambda { |_obj, inputs, ctx|
   (Auth.protect current_user = ctx[:current_user]
  if current_user.update(inputs.to_params)
    { user: current_user }
  else
    { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
  end)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that isn't valid ruby. This might work, but is ugly, because you're passing a multi-line block as a method argument.

```
resolve(Auth.protect lambda do (_obj, inputs, ctx)
  current_user = ctx[:current_user]
  if current_user.update(inputs.to_params)
    { user: current_user }
  else
    { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
  end
end)
```

You could make it more readable by doing something more like this:

```
auth = Auth.protect lambda do (_obj, inputs, ctx)
  current_user = ctx[:current_user]
  if current_user.update(inputs.to_params)
    { user: current_user }
  else
    { messages: current_user.fields_errors }
  end
end

resolve(auth)
```

Comment: But `lambda` doesn't work that way, `lambda do |_obj, inputs, ctx|` OTOH... Or more modern: `->(_, inputs, ctx) do ... end`

Comment: Using ->(_obj, inputs, ctx) will actually make rubocop mad and require the use of lambda for multi line

Comment: @Jake Really? RuboCop doesn't like `->(args) do ... end` and insists that stabby-lambdas are only used for brace-blocks (i.e. `->(args)  { ... }`)?

Comment: Yeah. RuboCop really does not like the stabby-lambdas.

Comment: @Jake Wow, that makes me feel a bit stabby about RuboCop.